# How do I align this long equation?

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, multline

My current code is like this:

```
\begin{multline}
Q_{K_4} =[l_1,(l_2,l_3),(l_4,l_5),(l_2,l_6,l_4),(l_5,l_6,l_3)].[l_2,l_3,(l_6,l_4),(l_6,l_5)].[l_4,l_6,l_5]\\
=\cfrac{l_1 (l_2,l_3)(l_4,l_5) (l_2,l_4,l_6)(l_3,l_5,l_6)}{(l_1,(l_2,l_3),( l_4,l_5),(l_2,l_4,l_6),(l_3,l_5,l_6))}.\cfrac{l_2 l_3(l_6,l_4) (l_5,l_6)}{(l_2,l_3(l_6,l_4),(l_6,l_5))}.[l_4,l_5,l_6]\\
=\cfrac{(l_4,l_5)(l_5,l_6)(l_6,l_4)[l_4,l_5,l_6]l_1 l_2 l_3 ( l_2,l_3 ) (l_2,l_4,l_6) (l_3,l_5,l_6)}{((l_1,l_2,l_3,(l_4,l_5)),(l_2,l_4,l_6,(l_3,l_5,l_6)))(l_2,l_3,l_6,l_4,(l_6,l_5))}\\
=\cfrac{l_4l_5l_6(l_4,l_5,l_6)l_1l_2l_3(l_2,l_3)(l_2,l_6,l_4)(l_5,l_6,l_3)}{ ((l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5),(l_2,l_4,l_6, l_3,l_5))(l_2,l_3,l_6,l_4,l_6,l_5)}\\ [\ (l_4l_5)(l_5,l_6)(l_6,l_4)[l_4,l_6,l_5] = l_4l_5l_6(l_4,l_5,l_6) ]\\
=\cfrac{l_1 l_2 l_3 l_4 l_5 l_6 (l_2,l_3)(l_2,l_4,l_6)(l_3,l_5,l_6)(l_4, l_5, l_6)}{((l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5 ),(l_2,l_3,l_4, l_5,l_6))(l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5,l_6)}
\end{multline}
```

But then it shows up like this. How do I align it properly, so that the equation number is also visible?
[image: code image]

Comment: You have to use the  `align` environment, and mark the alignment point  (`=`, I suppose) in each row with an  ampersand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m not sure I’m understanding what you’re asking for, but is it something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern} % Or your font of choice.
\usepackage{amsmath} % Already loaded.

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
Q_{K_4} &= [l_1,(l_2,l_3),(l_4,l_5),(l_2,l_6,l_4),(l_5,l_6,l_3)].[l_2,l_3,(l_6,l_4),(l_6,l_5)].[l_4,l_6,l_5]\\
        &= \cfrac{l_1 (l_2,l_3)(l_4,l_5) (l_2,l_4,l_6)(l_3,l_5,l_6)}{(l_1,(l_2,l_3),( l_4,l_5),(l_2,l_4,l_6),(l_3,l_5,l_6))}.
           \cfrac{l_2 l_3(l_6,l_4) (l_5,l_6)}{(l_2,l_3(l_6,l_4),(l_6,l_5))}.[l_4,l_5,l_6]\\
        &= \cfrac{(l_4,l_5)(l_5,l_6)(l_6,l_4)[l_4,l_5,l_6]l_1 l_2 l_3 ( l_2,l_3 ) (l_2,l_4,l_6)
           (l_3,l_5,l_6)}{((l_1,l_2,l_3,(l_4,l_5)),(l_2,l_4,l_6,(l_3,l_5,l_6)))(l_2,l_3,l_6,l_4,(l_6,l_5))}\\
        &= \cfrac{l_4l_5l_6(l_4,l_5,l_6)l_1l_2l_3(l_2,l_3)(l_2,l_6,l_4)(l_5,l_6,l_3)}{ ((l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5),
           (l_2,l_4,l_6, l_3,l_5))(l_2,l_3,l_6,l_4,l_6,l_5)}\\
        &\qquad [\ (l_4l_5)(l_5,l_6)(l_6,l_4)[l_4,l_6,l_5] = l_4l_5l_6(l_4,l_5,l_6) ]\\
        &= \cfrac{l_1 l_2 l_3 l_4 l_5 l_6 (l_2,l_3)(l_2,l_4,l_6)(l_3,l_5,l_6)(l_4, l_5, l_6)}
           {((l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5 ),(l_2,l_3,l_4, l_5,l_6))(l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5,l_6)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern Book Sample]

Using `aligned` within an `equation` gets you aligned equations with a single number at the end.

Here is an example that combines `aligned` with `split` to give aligned, split equations.  I took the liberty of indenting for readability, making outer nested parentheses and brackets larger than the ones they enclose, and changing all the fractions to `\frac`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern} % Or your font of choice.
\usepackage{amsmath} % Already loaded.

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
Q_{K_4} &= \begin{split} &[l_1,(l_2,l_3),(l_4,l_5),(l_2,l_6,l_4),(l_5,l_6,l_3)].\\
 &\quad[l_2,l_3,(l_6,l_4),(l_6,l_5)].[l_4,l_6,l_5]
           \end{split}\\
        &= \begin{split} &\frac{l_1 (l_2,l_3)(l_4,l_5) (l_2,l_4,l_6)(l_3,l_5,l_6)}
                               {\bigl(l_1,(l_2,l_3),( l_4,l_5),(l_2,l_4,l_6),(l_3,l_5,l_6)\bigr)}.\\
                         &\quad\frac{l_2 l_3(l_6,l_4) (l_5,l_6)}{\bigl(l_2,l_3(l_6,l_4),(l_6,l_5)\bigr)}.[l_4,l_5,l_6]
           \end{split}\\
        &=   \frac{(l_4,l_5)(l_5,l_6)(l_6,l_4)[l_4,l_5,l_6]l_1 l_2 l_3 ( l_2,l_3 ) (l_2,l_4,l_6)
                   (l_3,l_5,l_6)}
                  {\Bigl((l_1,l_2,l_3,(l_4,l_5)\bigr),
                   \bigl(l_2,l_4,l_6,\bigl(l_3,l_5,l_6)\bigr)\Bigr)\bigl(l_2,l_3,l_6,l_4,(l_6,l_5)\bigr)}\\
        &= \begin{split} &\frac{l_4l_5l_6(l_4,l_5,l_6)l_1l_2l_3(l_2,l_3)(l_2,l_6,l_4)(l_5,l_6,l_3)}
                               { \bigl((l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5), (l_2,l_4,l_6, l_3,l_5)\bigr)(l_2,l_3,l_6,l_4,l_6,l_5)}\\
                         &\quad \bigl[ (l_4l_5)(l_5,l_6)(l_6,l_4)[l_4,l_6,l_5] = l_4l_5l_6(l_4,l_5,l_6) \bigr]
           \end{split}\\
        &= \frac{l_1 l_2 l_3 l_4 l_5 l_6 (l_2,l_3)(l_2,l_4,l_6)(l_3,l_5,l_6)(l_4, l_5, l_6)}
                {\bigl((l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5 ),(l_2,l_3,l_4, l_5,l_6)\bigr)(l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5,l_6)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern Sample]

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use `\cfrac` here. The ordinary `\frac` directive seems more appropriate. And, I'd replace all instances of `.` with `\cdot`.

Comment: @Mico I copied it from the code in the question, and changed only the environments. You could be right!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks @Mico I will do that

Comment: @Mico How do you know that the operation(s) used here are denoted by `\cdot`, not purposely by `.`? Or do you just want to point out a possible typo?

Comment: @CampanIgnis - I suppose I was about 98% certain that `\cdot` was the right symbol to replace the four instances of `.`.  What raised my subjective probability to near-cdrtainty was the presence of `.` between two `\frac` terms. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you not provide any information about your document. So we don't know the size of `\textwidth`, used fonts etc. This has strong influence on equation formatting (if there is enough space for equation number or it is necessary to make more breaks):

He case with bigger `\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % for bigger \textwidth
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:longequation}
\begin{aligned}
Q_{K_4}
& = \bigl[l_1,(l_2,l_3),(l_4,l_5),(l_2,l_6,l_4),(l_5,l_6,l_3)\bigr]{\cdot}
    \bigl[l_2,l_3,(l_6,l_4),(l_6,l_5)].[l_4,l_6,l_5\bigr]                                   \\
& = \frac{l_1 (l_2,l_3)(l_4,l_5) (l_2,l_4,l_6)(l_3,l_5,l_6)}
         {\bigl(l_1,(l_2,l_3),( l_4,l_5),(l_2,l_4,l_6),(l_3,l_5,l_6)\bigr)}{\cdot}
    \frac{l_2 l_3(l_6,l_4) (l_5,l_6)}
         {\bigl(l_2,l_3(l_6,l_4),(l_6,l_5)\bigr)}{\cdot}[l_4,l_5,l_6]                                       \\
& = \frac{(l_4,l_5)(l_5,l_6)(l_6,l_4)[l_4,l_5,l_6]l_1 l_2 l_3 (l_2,l_3)(l_2,l_4,l_6) (l_3,l_5,l_6)}
         {\bigl((l_1,l_2,l_3,(l_4,l_5)),(l_2,l_4,l_6,(l_3,l_5,l_6))\bigr)
          \bigl(l_2,l_3,l_6,l_4,(l_6,l_5)\bigr)} \\
& = \begin{multlined}[t]
        \frac{l_4l_5l_6(l_4,l_5,l_6)l_1l_2l_3(l_2,l_3)(l_2,l_6,l_4)(l_5,l_6,l_3)}
         {\bigl((l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5),(l_2,l_4,l_6, l_3,l_5)\bigr)
                (l_2,l_3,l_6,l_4,l_6,l_5)}{\cdot}\\
         \bigl[(l_4l_5)(l_5,l_6)(l_6,l_4)[l_4,l_6,l_5] = l_4l_5l_6(l_4,l_5,l_6)\bigr]
    \end{multlined}                                                                         \\
& = \frac{l_1 l_2 l_3 l_4 l_5 l_6 (l_2,l_3)(l_2,l_4,l_6)(l_3,l_5,l_6)(l_4, l_5, l_6)}
         {((l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5 ),(l_2,l_3,l_4, l_5,l_6))(l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5,l_6)}
\end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A case with smaller (standard `article`) `\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:longequation}
\begin{aligned}
Q_{K_4}
& = \begin{multlined}[t]
    \bigl[l_1,(l_2,l_3),(l_4,l_5),(l_2,l_6,l_4),(l_5,l_6,l_3)\bigr]{\cdot}  \\
    \bigl[l_2,l_3,(l_6,l_4),(l_6,l_5)].[l_4,l_6,l_5\bigr]                                   
    \end{multlined}                                                                          \\
& = \begin{multlined}[t]
    \frac{l_1 (l_2,l_3)(l_4,l_5) (l_2,l_4,l_6)(l_3,l_5,l_6)}
         {\bigl(l_1,(l_2,l_3),( l_4,l_5),(l_2,l_4,l_6),(l_3,l_5,l_6)\bigr)}{\cdot}\\
    \frac{l_2 l_3(l_6,l_4) (l_5,l_6)}
         {\bigl(l_2,l_3(l_6,l_4),(l_6,l_5)\bigr)}{\cdot}[l_4,l_5,l_6]                     
    \end{multlined}                                                                          \\
& = \frac{(l_4,l_5)(l_5,l_6)(l_6,l_4)[l_4,l_5,l_6]l_1 l_2 l_3 (l_2,l_3)(l_2,l_4,l_6) (l_3,l_5,l_6)}
         {\bigl((l_1,l_2,l_3,(l_4,l_5)),(l_2,l_4,l_6,(l_3,l_5,l_6))\bigr)
          \bigl(l_2,l_3,l_6,l_4,(l_6,l_5)\bigr)} \\
& = \begin{multlined}[t]
        \frac{l_4l_5l_6(l_4,l_5,l_6)l_1l_2l_3(l_2,l_3)(l_2,l_6,l_4)(l_5,l_6,l_3)}
         {\bigl((l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5),(l_2,l_4,l_6, l_3,l_5)\bigr)
                (l_2,l_3,l_6,l_4,l_6,l_5)}{\cdot}\\
         \bigl[(l_4l_5)(l_5,l_6)(l_6,l_4)[l_4,l_6,l_5] = l_4l_5l_6(l_4,l_5,l_6)\bigr]
    \end{multlined}                                                                         \\
& = \frac{l_1 l_2 l_3 l_4 l_5 l_6 (l_2,l_3)(l_2,l_4,l_6)(l_3,l_5,l_6)(l_4, l_5, l_6)}
         {((l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5 ),(l_2,l_3,l_4, l_5,l_6))(l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5,l_6)}
\end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]